# Selecting record range dynamically in a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big query to make and then I convert to JSON so I get OutofMemory Exception in JAVA during my conversion. What I'm trying to achieve is split the query dynamically calling it multiple time.

i.e

```
SELECT ROWS x/10 multiply by (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM myquery) to 
            y/10 multiply by (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM myquery) 
FROM myquery
```

I'm calling this query from a python script on a http endpoint so I can separate my load as to call it ten times for example replacing x , y by 1to10.

Example Select the first 0/10 to 1/10 records and then 1/10 to 2/10 and then 2/10 to 3/10 ... 9/10 to 10/10.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? (Later versions present more options...)

Comment: should have specified I am on SQLServer 2012

Comment: So you want a pagination? Like if you have 200 rows then return rows 1 to 20 then 21 to 40 .... 181 to 200 ?

Comment: Yea something like that. In short I want to separate my query in n sets in my question I put 10 but it might as well be 100. So I call my script on the first 10% of the records, then on the second 10% then on the third until I've gotten all my rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a field to order your rows call it `order_field`. And use the analytic function **[NTILE(10)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms175126.aspx)** to create 10 groups

Then pass a variable `@YourPage` to indicate what page you want

```
  SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT *,
               NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY order_field) as page_number
        FROM yourTable
       ) T
  WHERE T.page_number = @YourPage
```

Comment: is it possible to remove page_number in the colums?

Comment: Yes, Change the outside `SELECT *` with a list of the field you need `SELECT fieldname [, fieldname]`